# Error While creating user defined table type in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a user defined table type in SQL Server 2008 R2 version but unable to create.

Using the following query

```
create type <table_type_name> as table
(
UserId int,
FirstName varchar(50)
)
```

It shows the error message "157, Incorrect syntax near keyword AS."

Also I want to mention one thing that in the folder hierarchy of the SQL Server under the *Programmability* -> *Types* folder I am not able to see the folder "User Defined Table Type".

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You must specify the name of your user defined table, eg [TypeName} on the query. You must include square brackets if you want to use type as your user defined table name eg [type].

Use the following:

```
create type [TypeName] as table 
(UserId int, 
 FirstName varchar(50))
```

Comment: Your suggestion is correct, but it seems like the OP was aware about the name. You couldn't see that because their code snippet was not formatted as code and it contained 'arrow brackets' that were treated as tag delimiters (and, as a result, the 'tag' was hidden).

Comment: "You must include square brackets if you want to use type as your user defined table name" -- not quite true: double quotes also work.

Answer (score 3):

User-defined table types were introduced in SQL Server 2008. Possibly you are connecting to a SQL Server instance whose version is lower.

Comment: This was the answer for me. Use 'select @@version', if your sql server version is 2005 this won't work.